# GPUImage Camera Takes Five Seconds

Tags: ios, gpuimage

On an iPad Retina Display (the device, not simulator), I had first used Apple's AVFoundation to take still pictures, but I switched to GPUImage because I wanted the ChromaKeyBlend feature. Got that running. BUT, the issue is that when I tap my Camera button, with AVFoundation, the camera appeared immediately and with GPUImage it takes FIVE seconds!

Is that loading time to be expected? I understand it has to be synchronous and can't be in the background.

So, what are others doing to speed that up, or are they just putting an activity indicator on the screen and make the user wait those five seconds?

Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: With Instruments, it seems it takes 3.6 seconds to `[[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage smoothlyScaleOutput:YES]` for a 2420x1936 pixel image. What I did was do this processing in the background queue of the parent view controller, and pass the processed image to the camera view during the segue. Now if they try to use the camera before 3.6 secs, haven't figure that out yet ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am loading an image into GPUImagePicture, but I think I have the pipeline right, and I really like the real-time adjustment of the sensitivity (with a slider). As I said, I tried to preprocess the image in the background and shaved off some seconds (this takes 5 sec still, even if I use a completely transparent image at the same size). Hope there is some secret sauce ;)

```
stillCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] init];
stillCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;

UIImage *inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"RedCurtain-60-8x10.jpg"];  // 346kb
self.sourcePicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];
[self.sourcePicture processImage];

self.chromaKeyBlendFilter = [[GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter alloc] init];
[self.chromaKeyBlendFilter setColorToReplaceRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0];
[self.chromaKeyBlendFilter setThresholdSensitivity:0.35f];

[stillCamera addTarget:self.chromaKeyBlendFilter];
[self.sourcePicture addTarget:self.chromaKeyBlendFilter];
[self.chromaKeyBlendFilter addTarget:(GPUImageView *)self.videoPreviewView];
```

Comment: It was the sourcePicture and its processing that was the problem. Instead of using an image with content I tried a transparent image that was 2420x1936 and it cut out about a second. Then, I tried a 1x1 pixel transparent PNG and the processing was sub-second with the the chromakeyed output appearing as black for the entire screen.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're not using a GPUImageStillCamera as your input to the GPUImage pipeline. Using a UIImage, particularly one passed into a new GPUImagePicture instance with smooth scaling set to YES, will be much, much slower than having the photo be captured and processed directly from the camera. Capturing from the camera via AV Foundation, converting that to a UIImage, then re-uploading that UIImage to the GPU through a GPUImagePicture introduces a significant amount of unnecessary overhead. Use a GPUImageStillCamera instead for best performance.

Look at the SimplePhotoFilter example for how this is done. When I test that application on my Retina iPad (3rd generation, not 4th), it takes a total of 0.9 seconds to take, filter, and return a full photo, and an additional 0.6 seconds to save that photo to the camera roll.

Comment: But the JPEG method rotates the image.